# How can I get individual image_urls from an Instagram album using oembed api call?

Tags: instagram-api

I have been using the Instagram API to get images and videos, which works just fine. I then noticed the oembed API call, which does not require an access_token, and I decided to give that a try, which also worked just great as the thumbnail_url size is adequate for most uses.
However, I noticed that the images retrieved from an album, all have a thumbnail_url that returns a 5xx Error from Instagram.

**My thinking is that:**

a) This is exactly how it is supposed to work and if I want images from a gallery/album, I need to use the media API call and access_token like most normal people

b) There is a way to access all images from a gallery/album and I just don't know yet. What if I want to embed the album? If this is the case, how can I check if it is an album or single image before making an API call?

**Here is what I have so far:**

***Instagram permalink for album/gallery:*** `https://www.instagram.com/p/BTHpAmzDHKR/`

***OEMBED API call:*** `https://api.instagram.com/oembed/?url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.instagram.com%2Fp%2FBTHpAmzDHKR%2F`

***thumbnail_url returned:*** `https://scontent-dft4-2.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s612x612/e35/18012162_1608580785827161_2716056344971968512_n.jpg`

***media API working url for same image:***

```
https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/18012162_1608580785827161_2716056344971968512_n.jpg
```

This opens up to a **5xx Server Error**

Is it possible or not using oembed call?

**NOTE:** I am trying this just out of curiosity and not for any real app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this out as my research has shown that oembed is for single media type only, not for carousel/albums. Instagram API call which uses tokens is required.